# How to affect html elements in component

Tags: angular, dialog, modal-dialog, angular-ui-router, angular-components

I have navbar component and in this nav component I have login and registration button. I have used this navbar component in different pages. When I click the login button in navbar I want to appear dialog box in other component where I have used this nav component.

I gave id "#Login" to dialog and I made onclick function in nav component (click)="#Login.showModal" but because the #Login is in different component click function gives me error because there is not #Login dialog box in navbar component.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to trigger an event or changes inside a component from another component, its best practice to implement an Angular Service for that feature.
Example:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService {
  private eventSubject = new Subject<void>();

  get event$() {
    return this.eventSubject.asObservable();
  }

  triggerEvent() {
    this.eventSubject.next();
  }
}
```

Now you can use this Service inside your to components. One Component will trigger the event, the other one listens (subscribes) to this event:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MyService } from './my.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  template: '<button (click)="onClick()">Click me</button>'
})
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

  onClick() {
    this.myService.triggerEvent();
  }
}
```

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MyService } from './my.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-another-component',
  template: '<p>Event received: {{ eventReceived }}</p>'
})
export class AnotherComponent {
  eventReceived = '';

  constructor(private myService: MyService) {
    this.myService.event$.subscribe(() => {
      this.eventReceived = 'Event triggered!';
    });
  }
}
```

Hope it helps!
Let me know if you need anything further.